# New JButton added after repaint is not shown

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel with a drawn picture (created by paintComponent) and a JButton in front of the picture. Everything looks fine when I start the programme. After a click on the button the picture is redrawn using repaint, the JButton is removed and a new JButton is added instead. This new JButton should be in front of the drawing, but becomes visible only after I hover the mouse over it. What is the reason for this behaviour and how can I fix it? Schematic of my code, with all non-relevant parts left out:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //draw picture
}

private void updateDrawing(){
    repaint();
}

public void updateButton(){
    //remove button from JPanel
    //add new button to JPanel
    ActionListener pressButton = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            updateDrawing();
            updateButton();
        }
    };
    button.addActionListener(pressButton);
    panel.add(button);
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    updateButton();
}
```

Comment: Try inverting order of adding button and repainting. You could also try calling `revalidate()`.

Comment: [`validate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate()) should be used when adding components to an already visible container: "*Layout-related changes, such as setting the bounds of a component, or **adding a component to the container**, invalidate the container automatically*" - You must validate the container